# Eloquent add default value in year format

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How can I use current year as default value in eloquent ?

```
Schema::create('year', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('from')->length(4)->default(1950);
    $table->integer('to')->length(4)->default('YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'); // this is not working
});
```

not even with `DB::raw('YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tackle this using model events.

Add the following code to your `Year` model:

```
/**
 * Model Events
 */
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model)
    {
        $model->to = date('Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a solution. But I guess laravel5.4 uses Observer for observing creating, created, deleting etc events. One tweak is if `from` & `to` are not provided then use `date('Y')` which makes more sense like mysql default.

Comment: Check [my answer based on Laravel - 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43743939/465560)

Answer (score 2):

A clearer solution is to define your column as:

```php
$table->year('to')->default(new Expression('(YEAR(CURDATE()))'));
```

without additional logic in your app.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#default-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it.

By the way you should use `increments`  and not `increment` and you cannot set `4` as second argument of `integer`.

If you insert data using Eloquent you can fill in current year by default when creating new record.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation worked.

`/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
use App\Model\Year;
use App\Observers\YearObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function boot()
     {
         Year::Observe(YearObserver::class);
     }
}
```

`/app/Observers/YearObserver.php`

```php
namespace App\Observers;
use App\Model\Year;

class YearObserver
{
    public function creating(Year $year)
    {
        if (empty($year->to) || !is_numeric($to)) {
            $year->to = date('Y');
        }
    }
}
```